# Should I install different drivers for GTX 1070 and GTX 1080 TI on the same system?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

When I am running a multi-GPU setup with extenders and some cards are 1070 and others are 1080TI, should I download and install the drivers for 1070 and then the drivers for 1080TI?

My instinct would say *yes* because different cards may have different driver optimisations, however when I download the drivers for both cards they are named exactly the same and have the exact same size - leading me to believe the drivers are exactly the same.

So should I still do the process twice, or is this only required when you are using cards from different series (e.g. 1070 and 980)?

Comment: The drivers are not neccessarily the same. Often an installer package can handle multiple devices and will install different features based on the device found.